# Will a party with 2 reavers (with no tank) be viable?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

Anyone tried running a party with 2 reavers (with no tank)? I've set up my protagonist as a reaver and would like to have Iron Bull too. Tanks are too good for me to give up right now and am wondering if anyone else have managed to run this theoretical setup and made it work?

Answer (score 1):

DAI is less insistent on the tank-DPS-healer paradigm than DAO and DA2. Reavers can still maintain aggro with the two taunt abilities, which are conveniently the first-tier abilities in the Vanguard tree. As for damage mitigation, Reavers excel at fighting with low health as I'm sure you know. Between that and the Guard mechanic, you should be fine.

However, if you are having trouble staying alive, try finding some Fade-Touched Obsidian. This material, when added as a masterwork component to any schematic, will grant +3 Guard on hit. This can be very vital to survivability in tough boss fights.